# Removing /Drupal from the URL-path

Tags: uri, .htaccess

I know this question has been asked many times for the past versions of Drupal, but none of the solutions I've found works for Drupal 7.12.

I used to have an .htaccess file placed inside the document folder alongside with Drupal, and it partially worked on older versions when entering the front- and live-page of my website (which you can now only enter via "default-URL").
For reference, you were able to to enter the live page with http://pavescorner.com/live, 
but after the patch and some other maintenances on my website, the link has to be like this http://pavescorner.com/drupal/live.

During those tests, when I tried to make another working .htaccess file, I accidentally destroyed the version working for me, and now you can only enter my homepage with the /drupal subdirectory.

What should I put in my .htaccess file so that /drupal doesn't appear in the URLs for my site?

Comment: You should definitely update your Drupal to the latest version. Then search for a solution to your actual problem.

Answer (score 1):

Using [mod_rewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/rewrite/) within .htaccess, in your server's document root. Untested, but something like this should work.

```
# Enable from .htaccess
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymLinks
# For all URLs not starting with drupal
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/drupal
# Serve the same content from the /drupal directory instead
RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://pavescorner.com/drupal/$1
```

Comment: Okay, this seems to working codeline indeed. Except there's one major problem regarding to myself: I'm only familiar with HTML and such, not anything regarding to servers and other network softwares. In other words, I have no idea how to configure this Apache-command in practice. Would there be any actual guides how to do this for a mere "internet browser"?

Comment: It's actually fairly straightforward: copy the above into a file called ".htaccess" (no file extension, make sure the leading "." is there), and upload it to the root folder on your server. Try accessing http://pavescorner.com/live after doing so, and post with the results if it doesn't work out.

Comment: Ah, it was simply just to create the .htaccess-file after all.
Now, I've done this. But unfortunately my homepage open as a blank page (pavescorner.com without "/drupal"), and other pages I enter like the live without /drupal I get a message saying "The requested document was not found on this server." This is when I placed the htaccess-file into my httpdocs, where the Drupal folder itself is located. And the previous working htaccess-file was located there too.

Comment: Hmm, but I'd have to place the htaccess into "main-top"-folder, then this is going to a little tricky sice I have no persmission to modify/add things there. So I'll have to wait until tomorrow to contact server host to give the permission to add the htaccess-file there.

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you have anything else being served from subdirectories from your root folder? Because this will redirect *all* traffic from /* to its counterpart in /drupal/*. If you don't have access to the root folder and/or other content lives there, it may be much more difficult to safely achieve what you're looking for. Knowing what else lives in that root folder would help immensely.

Comment: I'll making a list for you in moment, and post it as a text file either on pastebin or here if I find a way.

Comment: The best I found was to serve the file-list as images. First first the root-folder, which open when I connect with FTP-client: http://www.mediafire.com/?yxmj82m9biatt02

Comment: (Drat, pressed Return/Enter accidentally).
The second image is the container of httpdocs: http://www.mediafire.com/?1s66b3z8nf75ewh
That htaccess is the one suggested there. And ehre located the one which was working previously.
that index-html on contains line:
<html>
<head>
<meta url=http://pavescorner.com/drupal>
</head>
</html>
and changing that helped nothing.

Comment: Did some digging on older replies and actually found the solution which worked before. All I needed was <br/>
_RewriteEngine on<br/>
RewriteRule (.*) drupal/$1 [L]_<br/>
and now it work like it used to.
However, this only work if you insert the link directly in url and won't work with Archive page, which itlsef is a module. So, tou enter directly to homepage, Live and About without /drupal. But anything has things to do with Archive work without /drupal.

Comment: Of course, since the menu is directly linked to node itself instead of them having own custom handcrafted link, the /drupal appears on those items, which in end is not going to be a huge issues, but it may confuse some of the newcomers for my website.

Comment: Okay, it seems I've partially celebrated too early, because the direct linking to static/article-pages seemed only to be temporal for some off reason; now it's doing the same thing it's been doing with every page inserted without /drupal, which makes people to enter the front page itself.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your root is changed to drupal.

Follow some steps which could help you to solve your problem.

1. go to etc/hosts file. add your sites address with the name you wanted to set it to be. (Domain name)

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1  abc.com
```

2. In httpd.conf file. add following lines which makes your drupal as root.

> ```
>  <VirtualHost yourproject.com>    
>         DocumentRoot path_upto_your_project_directory/yourprojectdirectoryroot   
>         ServerName yourproject.com   
>     </VirtualHost>
> ```

hope this will solve your problem.